# Nginx latency is too high

Tags: php, nginx, connection, response

I use 2 servers for php and mysql.
users connect via Cloudflare > Varnish > Ngnix > Php-fpm --> Mysql Server
But i connected my website with nginx port directly so that was same

My server properties are 16 GB ram, E3-1231v3 cpu (8 core)
Server load is always 1.30 and free ram is 3 gb But at weekend, my website gets a lot of traffics and sometimes website response is late, it likes freezing. 
When i check php-fpm and nginx connections, php-fpm is usually at 30-40 but it has seen max 650.
Nginx is usually 100 but that sometimes comes to 400-500-600 and starts to freezing, I see writing connections increase same with nginx connections at the same time and website response become late.

I setup munin and monitored nginx, php-fpm and network they are like that.

[image: s]
[image: s]
[image: s]
[image: s]
[image: s]

And my nginx conf like that

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /var/run/nginx.pid;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log info;
worker_rlimit_nofile 65536;

events {
worker_connections 65536;
use epoll;
multi_accept on;
}

http {

##
# Basic Settings
##
log_format  main  '$http_cf_connecting_ip - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" ' '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" ' '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
log_format combined2 '$http_cf_connecting_ip - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" ' '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" ' '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

sendfile on;
keepalive_timeout 15; #65;
keepalive_requests 100000;
tcp_nopush on;
tcp_nodelay on;
types_hash_max_size 2048;
# server_tokens off;
client_body_buffer_size 10K; #15M;
client_max_body_size 10M;

# send_timeout 10;
client_header_buffer_size 10k;
large_client_header_buffers 2 10k;
output_buffers 1 32k;
postpone_output 1460;
client_header_timeout  12; #4m;
client_body_timeout    12; #4m;
send_timeout           10; #4m;
open_file_cache max=1000 inactive=5m;
open_file_cache_valid 2m;
open_file_cache_min_uses 5;
open_file_cache_errors off;
# server_names_hash_bucket_size 64;
# server_name_in_redirect off;

include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type application/octet-stream;

##
# SSL Settings
##

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

##
# Logging Settings
##

access_log off; #/var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log off; #/var/log/nginx/error.log;

##
# Gzip Settings
##

gzip on;
gzip_disable "msie6";

gzip_vary on;
# gzip_proxied any;
gzip_comp_level 2;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
# gzip_http_version 1.1;
# gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

##
# Virtual Host Configs
##
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
upstream backend {
server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
# Cloudflare
set_real_ip_from 199.27.128.0/21;
set_real_ip_from 173.245.48.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 103.21.244.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.22.200.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 103.31.4.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 141.101.64.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 108.162.192.0/18;
set_real_ip_from 190.93.240.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 188.114.96.0/20;
set_real_ip_from 197.234.240.0/22;
set_real_ip_from 198.41.128.0/17;
set_real_ip_from 162.158.0.0/15;
set_real_ip_from 104.16.0.0/12;
real_ip_header CF-Connecting-IP;
real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
}
```

I suspect network bandwith and nginx config, Do you have any idea?

Comment: Without Nginx access log file it extremely hard to understand what causes the slowness so the question is too broad. Can you share access log please?

Comment: I have 1.5GB log, what needs exactly?

Comment: What exactly needed is logs with $request_time, $upstream_header_time and $upstream_connect_time variables around the time where the slowness being experienced.

Comment: Thanks Anatoly, i didn't keep those data but i set nginx.conf again